# What component to use to make a toolbar under android?

Tags: android, toolbar

I've been using the component `Gallery` has a toolbar, but I'm not so much satisfied because I didnt find how to set up her position on init.

Does anybody know a component to use to have kind of 5 or more icons, kind of toolbar to use under android.

Can you give a code example?

Answer (score 1):

Why not a simple horizontal LinearLayout containing Buttons or ImageButtons ? You can even make it scrollable by placing the LinearLayout in a ScrollView.

Comment: But can you manage the fact to explicitly scroll to one image button automatically by code ? Is this possible ? is this complex ?